SwiftUI blur breaking scrollview layout
In SwiftUI, I found that adding a blur to some page content which has a ScrollView breaks the layout by adding some unexpected inset at the top of the ScrollView. I have made a minimal reproducible example as follows
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.orange)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.purple)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Button("Click me") {
                        isActive = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .blur(radius: isActive ? 10 : 0)
            
            if isActive {
                Color.clear
                    .background(.black.opacity(0.1))
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isActive = false
                    }
                    .border(.orange)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

To see the issue in action, run the app, scroll down to activate the overlay. Next, tap on the status bar to scroll all the way to the top. Tapping on the overlay deactivates it, but the ScrollView is now offset downwards by about 20px. It seems this issue does not occur if no blur is applied to the content.
Clicking the status bar to scroll to the top is the most solid way I've found to reproduce the issue, but it sometimes happens when just clicking the overlay normally to dismiss it.
Does anyone know what is causing this? Is this a bug in SwiftUI or am I doing something wrong? I have observed this issue in iOS 17.5 and the iOS 18 beta with XCode 15.4
Edit: Adding some images

Initial state

After following the steps above


Actions taken

Debug View Hierarchy
From the debug view hierarchy, it seems the elements are offset from where they end up being rendered by about 20px



I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. Can you show a screenshot?

Hello @Sweeper, thank you for taking a look. I've updated the question to include screenshots and a gif as well as a screenshot of the debug view hierearchy which shows the broken layout

The problem is not the blur but this code
Color.clear
     .background(.black.opacity(0.1))
     .contentShape(Rectangle())
     .onTapGesture {
          isActive = false
     }
     .border(.orange)

If you add a frame to this Color block then the problem does not occur.
Color.clear
     .background(.black.opacity(0.1))
     .contentShape(Rectangle())
     .onTapGesture {
          isActive = false
     }
     .border(.orange)
     .frame(height: 200)

or
Color.clear
  .background(.black.opacity(0.5))
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
  .onTapGesture {
       isActive = false
  }
  .border(.orange)
  .ignoresSafeArea()

The above 2 block of codes don't create this problem.
I am adding below the modified code that is working fine.


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.orange)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.purple)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.yellow)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                    Button("Click me") {
                        isActive = true
                    }
                }
            }
            .blur(radius: isActive ? 10 : 0)
            .onTapGesture {
                isActive = false
            }


        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}




Unfortunately, this doesn't work

Is it the same problem, because this is working fine on my playground
